# pandas dataframe wide to long

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
id  type  count_x count_y count_z sum_x sum_y sum_z
1    A      12      1        6     34    43     25
1    B      4       5        8     12    37     28
```

Now I want to transform it by grouping by `id` and `type`, then transforming from wide to long like so:

```
id  type   variable  value  calc
1    A       x        12    count
1    A       y        1     count
1    A       z        6     count
1    B       x        4     count
1    B       y        5     count
1    B       z        8     count
1    A       x        34    sum
1    A       y        43    sum
1    A       z        25    sum
1    B       x        12    sum
1    B       y        37    sum
1    B       z        28    sum
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for the dataframe so we can copy and run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `melt`:

```
res = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['id', 'type'])
res[['calc', 'variable']] = res.variable.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

---

|  | id | type | variable | value | calc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | x | 12 | count |
| 1 | 1 | B | x | 4 | count |
| 2 | 1 | A | y | 1 | count |
| 3 | 1 | B | y | 5 | count |
| 4 | 1 | A | z | 6 | count |
| 5 | 1 | B | z | 8 | count |
| 6 | 1 | A | x | 34 | sum |
| 7 | 1 | B | x | 12 | sum |
| 8 | 1 | A | y | 43 | sum |
| 9 | 1 | B | y | 37 | sum |
| 10 | 1 | A | z | 25 | sum |
| 11 | 1 | B | z | 28 | sum |

### Update:

Using `stack`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id', 'type']).stack().rename('value').reset_index())
df1 = df1.drop('level_2',axis=1).join(df1['level_2'].str.split('_', 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'calc', 1:'variable'}))
```

---

|  | id | type | value | calc | variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | 12 | count | x |
| 1 | 1 | A | 1 | count | y |
| 2 | 1 | A | 6 | count | z |
| 3 | 1 | A | 34 | sum | x |
| 4 | 1 | A | 43 | sum | y |
| 5 | 1 | A | 25 | sum | z |
| 6 | 1 | B | 4 | count | x |
| 7 | 1 | B | 5 | count | y |
| 8 | 1 | B | 8 | count | z |
| 9 | 1 | B | 12 | sum | x |
| 10 | 1 | B | 37 | sum | y |
| 11 | 1 | B | 28 | sum | z |

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of melt and split()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1], 'type': ['A', 'B'], 'count_x':[12,4], 'count_y': [1,5], 'count_z': [6,8], 'sum_x': [34, 12], 'sum_y': [43, 37], 'sum_z': [25, 28]})

df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'type'])

df_melt[['calc', 'variable']] = df_melt['variable'].str.split("_", expand=True)

df_melt



    id  type    variable    value   calc
0   1   A   x   12  count
1   1   B   x   4   count
2   1   A   y   1   count
3   1   B   y   5   count
4   1   A   z   6   count
5   1   B   z   8   count
6   1   A   x   34  sum
7   1   B   x   12  sum
8   1   A   y   43  sum
9   1   B   y   37  sum
10  1   A   z   25  sum
11  1   B   z   28  sum
```

Comment: you don't need to mention columns in  `value_vars` because by default `value_vars `  will take rest of the `non` `id_vars` columns. Happy Learning :) +1

Comment: oh that's good to know. Saves some effort. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your pandas DataFrame is `df_wide`, you can get the desired result in `df_long` as,

```
df_long = df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'type'], value_vars=['count_x', 'count_y', 'count_z', 'sum_x', 'sum_y', 'sum_z'])
df_long['calc'] = df_long['variable'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
df_long['variable'] = df_long['variable'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
```

Comment: Try to avoid apply as much as you can since it's slow. you don't need to define `value_vars` because by default it will take rest of the `non id_vars columns`. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape the data using [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
df.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'type'], 
                # names of the new columns
                # note the order
                names_to = ['calc', 'variable'], 
                values_to = 'value', 
                # delimiter for the columns
                # first value is assigned to `calc`, 
                # the other goes to `variable`
                names_sep='_')
 
    id type   calc variable  value
0    1    A  count        x     12
1    1    B  count        x      4
2    1    A  count        y      1
3    1    B  count        y      5
4    1    A  count        z      6
5    1    B  count        z      8
6    1    A    sum        x     34
7    1    B    sum        x     12
8    1    A    sum        y     43
9    1    B    sum        y     37
10   1    A    sum        z     25
11   1    B    sum        z     28
```