# Long to wide format using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a long to wide transformation of my dataframe, starting from

```
match_id player goals home
1        John   1     home
1        Jim    3     home
...
2        John   0     away
2        Jim    2     away
...
```

ending up with:

```
match_id player_1 player_2 player_1_goals player_2_goals player_1_home player_2_home ...
1        John     Jim      1              3              home          home
2        John     Jim      0              2              away          away
...
```

Since I'm going to have columns with new names, I though that maybe I should try to build a dictionary for that, where the outer key is match id, for everylike so:

```
dict = {1: {
    'player_1': 'John',
    'player_1_goals':1,
    'player_1_home': 'home'
    'player_2': 'Jim',
    'player_2_goals':3,
    'player_2_home': 'home'
     },
        2: {
    'player_1': 'John',
    'player_1_goals':0,
    'player_1_home': 'away',
    'player_2': 'Jim',
    'player_2_goals':2
    'player_2_home': 'away'

     },
}
```

and then:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict).T
```

In the real case scenario, however, the number of players will vary and I can't hardcode it.

Is this the best way of doing this using diciotnaries? If so, how could I build this dict and populate it from my original pandas dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas dataframe wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369929/pandas-dataframe-wide-to-long)

Comment: dang used the wrong search term order. here's one: [pandas long to wide reshape by two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape-by-two-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to pivot the dataframe. The problem is there is no column in your dataframe that "enumerates" the players for you. If you assign such a column via `assign()` method, then `pivot()` becomes easy.

So far, it actually looks incredibly similar [this case here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73060100/19123103). The only difference is you seem to need to format the column names in a specific way where the string `"player"` needs to prepended to each column name. The `set_axis()` call below does that.

```py
(df
 .assign(
     ind=df.groupby('match_id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
 )
 .pivot('match_id', 'ind', ['player', 'goals', 'home'])
 .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis([
     '_'.join([c, i]) if c == 'player' else '_'.join(['player', i, c]) 
     for (c, i) in x
 ], axis=1))
 .reset_index()
)
```

[image: res]